# Set role to oracle database user on django orm

Tags: python, django, django-models, oracle11g

I need to integrate a legacy oracle database into a django application. Basically I need to map some tables into django models.

The connection is working fine, as following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'orad03',
        'USER': 'u_hrp',
        'PASSWORD': 'myp4ssw0rd',
        'HOST': 'myhost.com.br',
        'PORT': '1521'
    }
}
```

My problem here is that, the application tables is under the owner ADM_HRP, the application use the user U_HRP (which have no privileges at all). The privileges to INSERT, DELETE, SELECT, etc, is on the role R_HRP.

So, on the legacy ASP/VbScript application it sets the role right after making the connection:

```
Sub Connect()
    Set objConexao = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConexao.Mode = 3
    objConexao.CommandTimeout = 90

    Dim strDSN

    strDSN="DSN=orad03;Uid=u_hrp;Pwd=myp4ssw0rd;"
    objConexao.Open strDSN
    objConexao.execute "SET ROLE R_HRP IDENTIFIED BY " & chr(34) & "myp4ssw0rd" & chr(34)
End Sub
```

I need to do the same thing on my django application, manage to run the SET ROLE statement right after opening the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's any option by default. But I think that you can achieve your goal with Django signal (hook).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#connection-created

**connection_created** signal is called after a new connection to database is successfully made. It gives you a connection object. So you can do something like:

```
from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created

def set_role(**kwargs):
    connection = kwargs.get("connection", None)
    if connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SET ROLE R_HRP IDENTIFIED BY %s", "myp4ssw0rd")

connection_created.connect(set_role)
```

I don't have oracle database and hadn't tested that either, but it should point you the right direction.

Comment: It seems like a good approach. I will test it out as soon as possible